# How to tryCatch in R cfa of lavaan library (and inspect errors, but get variable)?

Tags: r, loops, error-handling, warnings, r-lavaan

I do simulation research and create different datasets for different CFA models. During a series of simulations, I would like to handle errors resulting from e.g. randomization. Specifically - I would like to be able to repeat the sampling procedure in the case of lavaan::cfa errors, but in the case of just warnings, I would only mark them in the output data.

Additionally - the lavaan error breaks the loop, while the warning does not break the loop.

Unfortunately, the "normal" tryCatch procedure (probably) deletes the created variable in both cases, and returns NULL on also warnings. Please, look at my code:

```
# I do a simple procedure that just inherites lavaan:cfa
my_fit_function <- function(input_model,input_frame){
    tryCatch(
        {
        my_fit <- cfa(input_model, data=input_frame)
        return(my_fit)
        # and here should be some info about warnings
        }, warning = function(warning_condition) {
            message("warning; do i have output variable?:")
            message(exists("my_fit"))
            message(warning_condition)
        }, error=function(error_message) {
            message("error; do i have output variable?:")
            message(exists("my_fit"))
            message(error_message)
        }
    )
}
```

While execution on dataset that ends with a lavaan warning on the original procedure gives:

```
fit <- cfa(model, data=df)
(...) lavaan WARNING: covariance matrix of latent variables (...)
exists("fit")
> TRUE
```

I got my variable and everything seems OK, BUT when i use my procedure i got something like this:

```
fit <- my_fit_function(model, df)
> warning; do i have output variable?:
> FALSE
> 0
fit
> NULL
```

so the original function itself rather executes, but at the tryCatch level my_fit returns NULL to me.

What am I doing wrong, or I don't understand? I would be grateful for the tip.

EDIT: if someone want to replicate exact this mine problem with lavaan warning, heres the initial code:

```
library(simstudy)
model <- "f1 =~ q1 + q4 + q7 + q10\nf2 =~ q2 + q5 + q8\nf3 =~ q3 + q6 + q9"
mu<-rep(0,10)
df = genCorGen(1000, nvars = 10, params1 = mu, params2 = (mu+1), dist = "uniform", rho = .9, corstr = "cs", wide = TRUE)
df = as.data.frame(df[,-1])
colnames(df) <- do.call('paste0',expand.grid("q", c(1:10)))
my_fit <- cfa(model, data=df)
> lavaan WARNING: covariance matrix of latent variables
```

*Note that not every simulation like this gives you warning, some of random models allow to fit data without warnings, you ned to paste this code several times.*

What makes the problem is just an Heywood Case Example (mean correaltion around .9 and three factors): model is possible to execute (gives estimates and procedure ends with proper variable), but lavaan gives you warning about this possibility of model misspecification.

Comment: Have the error function return `error_message` and when needed test `inherits(fit, "error")`. And the variable name `error_message` is misleading, the value returned by the error handler is a list with two members, `message` and `call`. If an error occurred (if the `inherits` above returns `TRUE`) you can get the message with `conditionMessage(fit)`

Comment: I'm sorry, but none of this seems to work here. The call argument of tryCatch in R returns only message, call argument is invalid whatever syntax i made. Returning error_message does not supports my need - i need lavaan object in return. Function conditionMessage(fit) is not applicable for lavaan object. Maybe You can explain Your idea in other way?

Comment: You have posted a function  but not the model and data, there is no way for us to know what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, to be honest, i'm still confused why lavaan object is making a mess with standard tryCatch function, but i found some solution ispired by code [here](https://github.com/OpenMx/ezMx/blob/master/lavaan.to.openmx.R)

The function that works for me goes like this:

```
my_fit_function <- function(input_model,input_frame){
                   tryCatch(my_fit <-cfa(input_model, data=input_frame),
                   error = function(e) { 
                   cat(paste("Lavaan model not secified correctly -",e,sep="\n")) 
                   return(NULL) } )     
}
```

This results a NULL only when i got real error with data or model specification, at errors it still makes an model. Unfortunately, I cannot detect any warnings in this procedure, only an error. Hence, I cannot mark apart error OR warning in the output. But at least I don't have any bugs in functions preventing loop development - this form does not close the loop with error-break.

Maybe it will be useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

`tryCatch` returns the value of its first argument `expr` when everything goes as planned. When it doesn't it returns the return value of the condition handlers. In your use case in the question you have

1. the fitting function call, `cfa` which should return `my_fit`;
2. two condition handlers, `warning` and `error`.

When there is something wrong, control is passed to the handlers and they take as their argument the warning or error. There is no point to print whether `my_fit` exists because if the handlers are being executed then it does not exist, it was not created. In this case, `my_fit` is the condition and `conditionMessage` will retrieve the message R would have printed hadn't it been caught.

The example below is the example in [`help("cfa")`](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/lavaan/html/cfa.html) with an added variable `x10` in order to throw an error, see also [here](https://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/cfa.html). The warning and error handlers are kept as simple as possible to illustrate what is said above.

```r
library(lavaan)
#> This is lavaan 0.6-12
#> lavaan is FREE software! Please report any bugs.

my_fit_function <- function(input_model,input_frame){
  my_fit <- tryCatch(
    {
      cfa(input_model, data=input_frame)
    }, 
    # here should be some info about warnings
    # warning = function(w) w, 
    # and here about errors
    error = function(e) e
  )
  if(inherits(my_fit, "error")) {
    msg <- conditionMessage(my_fit)
    message(msg)
    invisible(NULL)
  } else {
    my_fit
  }
}

HS.model <- ' visual  =~ x1 + x2 + x3
              textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
              speed   =~ x7 + x8 + x9 + x10 '

fit <- my_fit_function(HS.model, HolzingerSwineford1939)
#> lavaan ERROR: missing observed variables in dataset: x10
fit
#> NULL
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I'm sorry, but this case also is not working properly. For error it works fine, but for warnings it does not return output variable (for warning in Your case return variable class is warning and it contains only warning message, not an output variable). As I wrote, in case of a warning, lavaan returns the variable correctly and displays the message, only in the form of tryCatch this variable is not available. I've already done the correct solution below.

Comment: @kwadratens But if the problem is now the warnings, then that's the easiest problem to solve, just delete or comment out the warnings handler and let R's native warning handler take care of it. Delete or comment out the line `warning = function(w) w,` (comma included) and that's it. Will edit. Done.